# How to deal with different icon sizes

Tags: flutter

When developing for iphone, in Xcode/Swift there is an asset file where you add all the icons your application will use with 1, 2 and 3x sizes. There is probably a similar thing with Android that I don't know yet.

When developing for Flutter:

- How do you deal with the different screen resolutions to use the right icon sizes?
- If similar to Xcode/Swift, where do you put those files and how do you get them? What about Android?

If you know a tutorial or web page, just let me know! The only ones that I found are only dedicated for app icon and launch screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the official documentation about resolution-aware-image. 
This is based on the device pixel ratio.

Here you have an example about the structure of your files.

```
  .../pubspec.yaml
  .../icons/heart.png
  .../icons/1.5x/heart.png
  .../icons/2.0x/heart.png
```

And this is how you have to declare the assets files into your `pubspec.file`

```
        flutter:
          assets:
            - icons/heart.png
```

This is the link: https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets

Comment: For every device whose `devicePixelRatio` I'm checking is resulting in 1.0! _Nexus 4, Nexus S, Nexus 6 or Galaxy Nexus_, no matter which device, when I'm doing this: `print('Device PR: ${ViewConfiguration().devicePixelRatio}');` the result is always 1.0. Therefore icons in folder 2.0x or 3.0x is not being used. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To add to @diegoveloper answer.

Some plugins like google-maps do not honour this standard and require you to call BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('icons/heart.png') which is not converted to the correct image. In this case you can get the correct image from AssetImage by first createLocalImageConfiguration using the BuildContext as defined [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/createLocalImageConfiguration.html). Then use this configuration to resolve the correct image as follows:

```
ImageConfiguration config = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);
AssetImage('icons/heart.png')
   .obtainKey(config)
   .then((resolvedImage) {
       print('Name: ' + resolvedImage.onValue.name);
    });
```

In summary

Create an asset folder with the naming [convention](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets):

```
pathtoimages/image.png
pathtoimages/Mx/image.png
pathtoimages/Nx/image.png
pathtoimages/etc.
```

Where M and N are resolutions (2.0x) or themes (dark).
Then add the image or all the images to the pubspec.file as either

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - pathtoimages/image.png
```

or

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - pathtoimages/
```

Load the images in using either AssetImage('pathtoimages/image.png') or resolving to the actual file name as mentioned above, depending on the library being used.